# How to assign values to an array by using an array passed in a constructor?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to assign the values to the array **products[]** using the array **arr[]** which is passed in the constructor. When I compile the code I get the error

> **Shop.java:10: error: not a statement
>
>           products[]=arr.clone();
>
>                   ^                                                                Shop.java:10: error: ';' expected
>
>      products[]=arr.clone();**

How can I resolve the error and assign the **arr[]** values to the **products[]**

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Shop{
    private String shopName;
    private String shopAddress;
    private String products[];

    public Shop(String name,String add, String[] arr){
        shopName=name;
        shopAddress=add;
        products[]=arr.clone();
    }
}
```

I haven't given all the code, but assume

**arr[]={"apple","orange","mango","banana"}**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `products` variable without `[]`, because `[]` belongs to `String` to make it a `String` array, and your variable is `products`:

```
class Shop{
     private String shopName;
     private String shopAddress;
     private String products[]; // to avoid confusion I'd use String[] products;

 public Shop(String name,String add, String[] arr){
     shopName=name;
     shopAddress=add;
     products = arr.clone();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code your variable's name is "products".
No need for [] after products.

try

```
  products = arr.clone();
```